# Is the Riemannian volume density in Normal Coordinates a pullback of the Euclidean density at the tangent space of the base point?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian Manifold and suppose that $J(x,y)$ is the volume density in normal coordinates based at $x$. In particular this means that we can write the Riemannian volume form as 
$$ dv_g = J(x,y)dy \quad J(x,y) = \sqrt{\det g_{ij}(y)}$$

Denoting the exponential map based at $x$ by $exp_x$ I've been told that one can show that
$$J(x,y) = |\det D_{exp_x^{-1}(y)}exp_x|$$

but I don't think this is the case. I think that the roles of the exponential map and the exponential map inverse should be switched.

**Question:** Is it true that for $y$ in this geodesic normal coordinate chart based at $x$ that 
$$J(x,y)dy = \left(exp^{-1}_x\right)^*(dx)$$
where $dx$ is canoncial volume measure on $T_xM \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$?

If this is true then $$J(x,y) = |\det\left( D_y exp_x^{-1}\right)|$$ which is different from the formula above.

Comment: I'm confused, to start with, by writing the determinant of a linear map from $T_xM$ to $T_yM$. How does this make sense?

Comment: @TedShifrin I think It's the determinant of the Jacobian of $exp_x$ evaluated at $exp_x^{-1}(y)$. Can this be?

Comment: That is still a linear map between two different vector spaces. That means that the determinant will change if you change bases.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah, I see. In Lee's smooth manifolds he says the pullback of a top form by $F:M \to N$ is given by $F^*(u(y)dy) = u \circ F \det (\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j}) dx$ so I think it is $(\det \frac{\partial exp^i}{\partial x^j})$. With regards to the main question though is it true that the pullback of the canonical volume form on $T_xM$ by $exp^{-1}$ is the Riemannian volume form?

Comment: No, this is not correct. The pullback by $\exp_p$ of the metric on $M$ is *not* the usual (flat) metric on $T_pM$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to (hopefully) clarify notation and what not, I'll reiterate a few points, and try and rephrase your statement with a bit more explicit detail about coordinates.

Let $M$, and $N$ be $n$-dimensional manifolds. Top forms in $\Lambda^n M$ can be written as $f\ dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$, where $f\in C^\infty M$, and likewise in $N$. Let $x^i$ and $y^i$ be local coordinates on $M$, and $N$, respectively, and let $\Phi:M\to N$ be a (local) diffeomorphism. We can write down the transformation law for the pullback of a top form in coordinates.
$$
\Phi^*(f\ dy^1\wedge\dots\wedge dy^n)=\det(d\Phi)(f\circ\Phi)dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n
$$
Where $\det(d\Phi)$ denotes the determinant of the Jacobian in the chosen local coordinates.

We ca write the Riemannian volume element as $\omega_g$. It is defined (pointwise) by
$$
\omega_g|_p=\left.d\nu^{\bar{1}}\wedge\dots \wedge d\nu^{\bar{n}}\right|_{p}
$$
Where $\nu^{\bar{i}}$ are oriented orthonormal coordinates at $p$ (bars just for clarity). That is, we can consider $\hat{\psi}:T_pM\to\mathbb{R^n}$ to be an orthonormal basis (i.e. global chart) for $T_pM$, and let $\psi=\hat{\psi}\circ\exp_p^{-1}$ be the chart induced by the exponential map and this basis. We can also choose another aribitraty oriented chart $\varphi$ containing $p$ with coordinates $x^i$. Using the pullback formula with the transition function $\Phi=\hat{\psi}\circ\exp_p^{-1}\circ\varphi^{-1}$, we have
$$
\Phi^*\left(d\nu^{\bar{1}}\wedge\dots\wedge d\nu^{\bar{n}}\right)=\det(d\Phi)dx^{1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n}
$$
This allows us to compute the coordinate representation of $\omega_g$ (though only at $p$; this need not apply even on a neighborhood). We are in a sense computing the determinant of $d\exp_p^{-1}$ (and *not* $d\exp_p$), but composed with charts so that it is a sensible operation.

The $\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}$ formula comes from the fact that pulling back the metric (i.e. applying the chain rule) gives us a relation between $\det(d\Phi)$ and $\det(g_{ij})$.
$$
g_{ij}=g\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)=g\left(\frac{\partial\nu^{\bar{k}}}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu^{\bar{k}}},\frac{\partial\nu^{\bar{l}}}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu^{\bar{l}}}\right)=\frac{\partial\nu^{\bar{k}}}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial\nu^{\bar{l}}}{\partial x^j}g\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu^{\bar{k}}},\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu^{\bar{l}}}\right)=d\Phi^{\bar{k}}_i\ d\Phi^{\bar{l}}_j\ g_{\bar{k}\bar{l}}
$$
Taking the determinant of both sides at $p$ and using $g_{\bar{k}\bar{l}}=\delta_{\bar{k}\bar{l}}$ gives the desired relation.

Does this clarify things at all?